# Android onNewIntent with several Activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app in which I want to import images sent by other apps. For this reason, I have an intent filter for `action.SEND`. In order to get to the intent data nevertheless whether the app is started new or simply brought to foreground, I set the activity `launchMode=singleTop` and also implemented `onNewIntent`.

So far, this works as expected.

But, my app consists of several activities (let's say A,B,C). Let's assume that the intent filter is in Activity A. When the user now navigates to Activity B and then switches to the other app to send an image to my app, Activity B is simply brought to front with no information about the SEND action. It jumps directly to `onResume`. (Note: the incoming intents have the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag set.)

Clearly, I can only put an intent-filter only in one Activity as otherwise, all of them would appear in the list of export targets.

How can I intercept the incoming SEND intent independent of which activity is active in my app currently?

Comment: `sent by other apps`. . `the incoming intents have the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag set.`. How do you know? Did you program those other apps?

Comment: No, but I can call getFlags() on the Intent.

Comment: You get that in onNewIntent? Does Android Gallery app cause onNewIntent?

Comment: yes (onNewIntent and onCreate) and yes, from the Gallery app

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?